# How to retrieve values of list in browser using web2py?

Tags: python, list, printing, return, web2py

I'm writing a TSP algorithm using python and the output is a list of node route like :
path [1,2,3,4,5] where each number is a key of city name.
now i need to retrieve the whole list in browser but i can't because i only get one value from the list when i use return path 
note : my code is running perfectly since the output appear in console window.
any ideas ??

simple example :

> ```
> file.py
> def temp():
> path=[1,2,3,4,5]
> return path
>
> file.html
> {{extend 'layout.html'}}
> <h1>{{=path}}</h1>
> ```

Comment: Do you want it to show up as: `'1 2 3 4 5'`?

Comment: it will be much better if it's looked like [1,2,3,4,5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it as:

```
path=[1,2,3,4,5]
return str(path)
```